# UI testing failure - did not receive view did disappear notifications within 2.0s error

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing my test suite UI automation with xcode 8. However I keep occurring into this problem while trying to dismiss alerts.

I am currently using the `addUIInterruptionMonitor` in order to dismiss my alerts, however when I call the interruption monitor to fire using `app.tap()`  I get the error **UI testing failure - did not receive view did disappear notifications within 2.0s error**

Why is this happening and how can I prevent this from happening?

Attached is my start up code for the app

```
 override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    XCUIApplication().terminate()
    continueAfterFailure = false
    app.launch()

    addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Enable Notifications") { (alert) -> Bool in
       let button =  alert.buttons["OK"]
        if button.exists{
            button.tap()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    app.buttons["Enable notifications"].tap()

    app.tap()

    XCTAssert(app.tabBars.buttons["Settings"].exists)
    app.tabBars.buttons["Settings"].tap()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add the monitor before `app.launch(`) and you'll not need `app.tap()`

Second, is the `app.buttons["Enable notifications"].tap()` the trigger for the alert to appear, if not, remove that line.

Third, if you return false on the monitor's handler, the system will tap the "cancel" button for that alert. I prefere to fail the test in this case since it's an unexpected system alert.